# Non Linkable Navigation Headers

Tags: 2007, navigation

In SharePoint 2007, can first level headers in the navigation pane be non linkable?  I don't want users to click on the headers and see the back-end.

Answer (score 3):

If you manage your links manually you are able to create Headings.  These navigation entries don't need a hyperlink. The links below the header can be normal links to the specific sites.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it using jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#mydiv a').removeAttr('href');

});
```